# glob pattern PYTHON - check if pattern matches to given paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

Hi guys I have a list with glob patterns in a Json :

```
{
    "Project/*",
    "Sales",
    "Test"
}
```

And I have paths saved as string in a array named log_paths,  they can look like this:

```
[
    "Project/component_x/doc/doc.rst",
    "Project/component_y/doc/doc.rst",
    "Project/component_z/doc/doc.rst",
    "Sales/doc/doc.rst",
    "Sales/doc/architecture.pml",
    "Test/test_cases/test.py",
    "Test/test2020/test2020.py",
]
```

I want to check if my glob pattern matches to my paths.

If it is matching I want to save only the beginning like in the json but instead * I want the part of the path too.

only save:

```
Project/component_x
Project/component_y
Project/component_z

Sales
Sales

Test
Test
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
for name in glob.glob('Project/*'):
    print name

for a in glob.glob('Sales'):
    print 'Sales'

for b in glob.glob('Test'):
    print 'Test'
```

edit: list in log_paths

```
import glob
for pat in log_paths:
    for x in glob.glob(pat):
        print x
```

For anything more fancy I recommend you learn how to use `re` regex to extract the part of the file path you actually wanted. `glob` is not intended for that

Comment: should add that the `Project/*` glob will only return the first subdir without recursion so it already matches what you wanted

Comment: Can I do that without actually writing glob.glob('Project/*)? Cause it shoulb be generic it can always change. I thought about iterating through the json. And my paths are saved in a variable "log_path", I'll edit the part of the question

Comment: And I have a question where am I looking right now for the matches? on my workspace? I cant want to look into this log_paths and see if there is any match

Comment: well if your log_paths array contains relative paths its from where ever your script is executed. you could prepend the log directory path and make it absolute path